# Logback configuration error when execute cucumber-selenium tests in parallel

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, logback

I've created an automation test framework with Cucumber-Selenium-SpringBoot-Junit-maven. I am using logback as my logging framework. When I execute my tests in single thread it never report any error. But when I execute tests in parallel, logback report errors and only start one feature test, other thread feature test all failed.

Here is my logback-spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration  scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" debug="false">
    <contextName>EssaLog</contextName>
    <property name="logPath" value="src/main/log/" />
    <!--Output to console-->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %contextName [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!--Output to file-->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<!--        <file>${logPath}EssaLog.log</file>-->
        <!-- Daily generate log file -->
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!--Log output pattern: daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${logPath}essa_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!--Delete log after 30 days-->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <!--Max size of log file-->
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <!--Output format：%d %thread %-5level %msg %n-->
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %contextName [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <!-- encode -->
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
    <!--TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL-->
    <!-- Package logging -->
    <logger name="EssaApplicationTests" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"/>

    <!-- Define multiple environment -->
    <springProfile name="ST">
        <logger name="EssaApplicationTests" level="DEBUG" />
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="SIT">
        <logger name="EssaApplicationTests" level="INFO" />
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - 'FileNamePattern' option has the same value "src/main/log/essa_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}.log" as that given for appender [file] defined earlier.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - Collisions detected with FileAppender/RollingAppender instances defined earlier. Aborting.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#earlier_fa_collision
```

Please notice this error only happened when tests executed in parallel.
Could anyone help me solve this issue? Any input is welcome. Thanks in advance.